# Here Flutter SDK (Explorer): How to retrieve details (e.g. contacts, fuelstation, evChargingPool)?

Tags: flutter, here-api

I was trying out the Flutter exmaples for the Here Flutter SDK (explorer). One use case would involve retrieving details about the found places. I checked the Place class and based on the nested details class I expected that I could retrieve detail Information about e.g., evChargingPools and the included charging station. Nevertheless detail information (contact, opening time ..) would also be of interest.

Unfortunately and independend of the type of query (TextQuery, PlaceIdQuery, CategoryQuery) i used, i could only retrieve the categories as part of the details node.

I am currently using the freemium version. I checked the documentation and at least up to my knowledge it does no state under which constraints (well excluded the case, the data does not exist) these detail information are included, or how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your CategoryQuery has to include the FuelStations Ids.
https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.13.2.0/dev_guide/topics/search.html#search-for-places-categories

So init a SearchEngine and a CategoryCategory with the area and the PlaceCategory.id(id: 7600)

Source for PlaceCategories: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html#400---transport

Sorry if i can't provide a SourceCode example (my app is written in Swift so no Flutter), but i can provide you a Postman Request for it :)